# A Google+ hangout

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I was thinking of ways we could promote our site, well here is an idea.  We can always give a hangout on air that will be broadcasted in our Google+'s page as well as on our YouTube channel (live).  The hangout will be recorded, so after it ends we can share the video.  The subject being on how StackExchange works and it's rules, and how Islam.SE works and it's rules.  Our Google+ page currently has more than 1000 followers and 1000 +1's/likes.

Requirements for volunteers:

1. Must be able to understand, and speak both the English and Arabic language
2. Must be able to speak both languages in enunciation/articulation so that the viewers can understand.
3. Must be able to read both languages perfectly
4. Must have a good quality head set
5. A fast connection,  a wired connection is recommended
6. Have a quiet space
7. Must have time
8. Must have experience in giving public speeches

Comment: Just be sure that your G+ page makes clear that the page is the UNOFFICIAL site. That's all we ask. :)

Answer (score 1):

We are still waiting for someone to volunteer to do the Hangout.  After posting the suggestion, I gone and created a YouTube account for us, I am working on verifying it once verified we can have a live hangout which can be seen by anyone on our Channel, and also we would be able to record the hangout.

[Mr Tamer Shlash](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/167/tamer-shlash) Alhamdulillah has finished ([this](http://tamershlashme.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/islam-stackexchange-site/))  so we will be using it.

When we start the presentation we will start of-course with:

بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم

and Insha'Allah after the Basmallah this:

إن الحمد لله نحمده، و نستعينه و نستغفره، و نعوذ بالله من شرور أنفسناو من سيئات أعمالنا، من يهدهه الله فلا مضل له، و من يضلل فلا هادية له، و أشهد أن لا إله إلا الله  و أشهد أن محمدا عبده و رسوله

Indeed all praises are due to God/Allah, and we trust in Him and seek His forgiveness, and we seek refuge In Allah from the evil that is within ourselves and from the evil that is within our deeds, whomsoever Allah has guided non can misguide, and whomsoever he misguided non can guide, and I witness that there is no god except of God/Allah and Muhammad is His messenger.

و بعد :

The presentation created by Mr Tamer:  http://tamershlashme.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/islam-stackexchange-site/

Edited presentation: https://sites.google.com/site/islamstackexchange/

the end: و الحمد لله رب العالمين

We are still looking for someone who can do it, if you think you can do it please tell us.

Comment: This is the link to our channel: http://www.youtube.com/user/IslamStackExchange

Comment: The presentation is very clear, and nicely written. Great efforts.

Comment: @mtk Alhamdulillah, I have edited it up a bit and provided translation to some of the words, you may find it as a download here: https://sites.google.com/site/islamstackexchange/  tell me what you think.